# Running GPU accelerated apps in a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: docker, machine-learning, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gpu

How can I set it up to be able to run GPU accelerated apps in a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Please share your DockerFile. And tell me more about the AMI id thing.

Answer (score 2):

Using Deep Learning AMI with Beanstalk may not be able to use some Beanstalk features like health monitoring, sqsd with worker env. In my case, I built a custom AMI from Beanstalk docker AMI and deployed the application using docker-compose with GPU enabled. Details are as follows:

1. check Beanstalk docker AMI in Beanstalk default config
2. start an EC2 instance with Beanstalk docker AMI on GPU instance type (ex: g4dn.xlarge)
3. Install Nvidia driver (required S3 access) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html

- 

```
sudo yum install -y gcc kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://nvidia-gaming/linux/latest/ .
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64*.run
nvidia-smi
```

4. Install NVIDIA Container Toolkit (DONOT INSTALL DOCKER - docker will be installed by Beanstalk) https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#installing-on-amazon-linux

- 

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/nvidia-docker.repo
sudo yum clean expire-cache
sudo yum install nvidia-docker2
```

5. Stop instance and create a AMI from that instance
6. Set your AMI ID to Beanstalk config
7. Deploy docker container with docker-compose.yaml (https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/)

- 

```
services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: all
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

**Note:** For beanstalk worker (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html)

> if you manage your Docker environment with Docker Compose, Elastic
> Beanstalk assumes that you run a proxy server as a container.
> Therefore it defaults to None for the Proxy server setting, and
> Elastic Beanstalk does not provide an NGINX configuration

- Nginx still be installed on EC2 instances by EB (just disabled). If you want to use nginx proxy and generating logs for enhanced health reporting, you can use .ebextensions configuration files (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) for create config file and start service (`sudo systemctl start nginx`)

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted by [Piotr Walczyszyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779311) (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license) in the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59035690/1) of the question [Running GPU accelerated apps in a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035690). Reposted here to conform to SO's Q&A format.

---

> This is how I managed to run GPU accelerated apps in a Docker
> container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It took me almost two days of
> trial and error runs, so I hope others will not waste time having this
> post here.
>
> These are the settings of my Elastic Beanstalk environment:
>
> 1. Set AMI ID to one those with the NVIDIA drivers and Docker preconfigured. I used **Deep Learning AMI (Amazon Linux) Version
>    25.3** - `ami-068d6d02d8775ec52`
> 2. Set Instance type to one of the EC2 instances with GPUs. I used `g3s.xlarge` as it seamed enough for what I needed to do.
> 3. In your app `Dockerfile` add following lines: `ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility`
> 4. In your app root folder create `.ebextensions/01-nvidia-docker.config` file and paste following code
>    there: ```yaml option_settings:   aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
>
>    ## I had to increase storage space for the docker to run my container
>
>    BlockDeviceMappings: /dev/xvdcz=:24:true
>
> commands:   configure_docker_run:
> # I had to update EB startup script so it passes `--runtime=nvidia` when running docker
> command: sed -i 's/docker run -d/docker run --runtime=nvidia -d/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh
> # Following line will be required if docker is updated to 19.1
> # command: sed -i 's/docker run --gpus all -d/docker run -d/' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh ```
>
> Now you can enjoy Docker container running on Elastic Beanstalk with
> NVIDIA GPU enabled.

Comment: Does this have CUDA drivers enabled so that we can use GPU for things like Pytorch?

Comment: @JamesParker As the answer mentions, this answer was copied from the question. I don't personally have any idea whether the answer is right, or not, and I don't know anything about the technology. However, as the author of this wiki answer, I'm the only one who gets pinged with comments under it. I would suggest posting a comment under the question itself, so that the question author is pinged. Since they're the one who wrote this answer, they would probably be able to help out.